# R combining data from separate tibbles

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two tibbles holding data from separate datasets.

(tibble1,tib_column1)   and  (tibble2,tib_column2)

I am aiming to combine them into the same table so that the result has the format:

```
  | tib_column1  | tib_column2 |
```

1

2

How would i go about doing this? Any help is appreciated. For reference I am using the library tidyverse.

Edit: the tibbles hold multiple columns, I am only trying to extract one from each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `bind_cols` (assuming both datasets have the same number of rows, and a single column)

```
library(dplyr)
out <- bind_cols(tibble1, tibble2)
```

---

If we have multiple columns, then `select` the column of interest

```
out <- tibble1 %>%
         select(tib_column1) %>%
         bind_cols(tibble2 %>%
                      select(tib_column2))
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `cbind`

```
cbind(tibble1['tib_column1'], tibble2['tib_column2'])
```

---

If we have a key column in both datasets and have unequal number of rows, an option is to do a join.  If the interest is to get all the rows from both the datasets, do a `full_join`

```
full_join(tibble1 %>% select(tib_column1, Postcode),
          tibble2 %>% select(tib_column2, Postcode), by = 'Postcode')
```

Comment: the tibbles hold multiple columns, but i am only trying to extract one from each. This is the reason the issue arose to begin initially

Comment: @aWildFruit Thanks, can you check my update

Comment: passes the following eror ; Error: Can't recycle `..1` (size 8017) to match `..2` (size 182).

Comment: @aWildFruit if the number of rows are different, you need a join.  Do you have any column that is common in both datasets as key column

Comment: Yes Postcode field. They do not hold identical data, but the titles are the same and in the same format (XXXX YYY)